# Qt5, Code::Blocks, undefined reference

Tags: c++, qt5, codeblocks

Пытаюсь добавить Qt5 в готовый проект. Возникли две ошибки: `undefined reference to "_imp___ZN12QApplicationC1ERiPPci'` и `undefined reference to "_imp___ZN12QApplicationD1Ev'`. Создал новый проект, именно Qt5. В нём всё работает. Скопировал настройки с того проекта в свой - ошибки остались. Настройки полностью идентичны. Версии всего - самые последние. Компилятор - GCC (C++). Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Comment: Интересно: переключил на 64 битную сборку, всё заработало. Но нужно именно 32 бит.

Comment: Для 32-разрядного проекта нужен 32-разрядный Qt.

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо. Что-то я не выспался. Простую проблему не смог решить.